# What is difference of test builds in teamcity and test builds in octopus?

Tags: unit-testing, msbuild, teamcity, octopus-deploy, teamcity-9.0

I've been searching for this but no answers.
I've created a unit test project in my solution.
Since we're planning to automate the testing. We don't know where to put it.
Will the teamcity test it or just build the test project? If it will going to be tested does it mean that it is ok not put it in octopus?

Answer (score 3):

You should run your tests in Team City, and fail the build if the tests fail.

Only if the tests pass should you allow the build artefacts to be sent to Octopus, which will then take care of deploying the software.

Comment: Thank you for this explanation. This explains the general test that ed answers.

Answer (score 1):

General test should be run on the build server but you may want to run integration tests from Octopus after the deployment has happened. An example of post-deploy testing would be something like Selenium smoke tests to ensure the deployment was successful and the application is running as expected (e.g. a website on IIS).

Generally you want tests to fail as early as possible (e.g. in UAT instead of production, in CI instead of Test/UAT etc..)

Comment: This is it. Thank you.I'll look for integration and general test samples after.